# Select Dropdown onChange options

Tags: php, jquery

I have a question that I am designing a webpage to process database. So the idea is,

1. I have a dropdown
2. When user click on of the options,
3. Directly open a new window containing another webpage
4. On the new page, getting the value from the `dropdown` on the new page for the database monitoring with `$_POST`

The problem is, When I click the option, it redirects to that new page but not in the form of a new window.
And how do I send the selected value to be used on the new page with

```
$newVal = strval($_POST['PROJECT_NAME']);
```

My code is,

```
<script>
            $(function(){
              $('#cd-dropdown').bind('change', function () {
                  var url = $(this).val(); // get selected value
                  if (url) { // require a URL
                      window.location = "monitorIndex.php"; // redirect
                  }
                  return false;
              });
            });
        </script>
```

And the markups:

```
$projectParse = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT_NAME FROM MASTER_DRAWING '
                                        . 'ORDER BY PROJECT_NAME ASC');
                                oci_execute($projectParse);

                                echo '<select name="cd-dropdown "id="cd-dropdown" class="cd-select">';
                                    echo '<OPTION VALUE="">PROJECT SELECT</OPTION>';
                                    while($row = oci_fetch_array($projectParse,OCI_ASSOC)){
                                        $projectName = $row ['PROJECT_NAME'];
                                        echo "<OPTION VALUE='$projectName'>$projectName</OPTION>";
                                    }
                                echo '</select>';
```

Comment: use window.open("monitorIndex.php");

Comment: thanks it works like charm. But how do I pass $projectName into that page using POST ??

Comment: Instead of calling 'window.location' within change function (window.location won't submit your form) , call ajax request along with your selected value and then on 'success' function of ajax function call your new webpage

Comment: @Silz I am kinda newbie on this stuff. Can you please help me to implement that ? I am kinda lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code

```
$('#cd-dropdown').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "monitorIndex.php",
      data: { PROJECT_NAME: id }
    })
  .done(function( msg ) {
      var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=800, height=800");
      myWindow.document.write(msg );
   });
 });
```

Comment: it doesn't work as well, when I choose one of the project, it does nothing :(

Comment: check the ajax call i have changed the post variable name as 'PROJECT_NAME'  . Try $_POST['PROJECT_NAME']  in your php file.

Comment: its weird that your code doesn't do anything at all

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
$('#cd-dropdown').change(function(){
    var id = $(this).val();
    window.location = 'monitorIndex.php?id=' + id;
});
```

Comment: this will need to use `GET` instead of `POST` and is right. Also, can use `window.opener.document.getElementById(..)` to get the value of the selected drop-down on the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

```
    This method should take you to new window with ProjectName in URL. 

    $('#dropdown').change(function(){
        var id = $(this).val();
        window.open ('monitorIndex.php?id=' + id ,'_blank');
    });



 Or another way is if you are using HTML5 , you can use local storage,
 You can basically keep the value on client side localstorage and can access it on any other page.

// Store
localStorage.setItem("projectname", "abc");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("projectname");
```

Comment: and then how to use that value in the new page ? using $_POST['projectName'] ??

Comment: are to able to get to new page with ProjectName in URL ? if yes 
you can access the value as $_GET['id']

Comment: window.open ('monitorIndex.php?id='+ id); go with this approach . and make sure you have id appended to url. you can put debugger and check in browser if id is appended to the url.